# Override commit-interval property in runtime from a bbdd query in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a job with a list of steps. I want that this steps use a commit-interval from a property in the database (using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and using the stepName as condition in the where of the SQL sentence) so I can change it at runtime between executions. It's this possible?

I readed that I can use a [**SimpleCompletionPolicy**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/repeat/policy/SimpleCompletionPolicy.html) instance to set the chunk size, but I didn't found where I could set this instance at runtime. Anybody can tell me a clue where I can search or What I can test?

I didn't found "commit interval" options in the Spring Batch Listeners.